# RoR: can't access helper method in simple-navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a helper method in my project that evaluates a user attribute called 'is_coach'. The following method works in my views and returns "true" or "false" depending on whether the current user is a 'coach' and logged in:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def is_coach?
    user_signed_in? ? current_user.is_coach : 'false'
  end

  protected

end
```

However, when it is referred to in my 'simple-navigation' menu, it is undefined:

```
undefined method `is_coach?'
```

I understand that this should inherit any methods available to the view that it sits in, which this appears to contradict.

```
#config/navigation.rb
SimpleNavigation::Configuration.run do |navigation|
  navigation.selected_class = 'current'
  navigation.items do |primary|
    primary.item :home, 'Home', '/'
    primary.item :home, 'Clients', '/clients', class: 'special', if: -> { is_coach? }
  end
end
```

This code is called by the following in my view:

```
<%= render_navigation %>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: where is the `current_user` definition?

Comment: Should have read 'is_coach?', my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `is_coach?` method should be defined in the `application_helper.rb` file, then it would be available everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In rails `helper` is a different folder so, you should provide your code in :

`application.html.rb`

```
 def is_coach?
   user_signed_in? ? current_user.is_coach : 'false'
 end
```